# Auth0 flow between client to service

Tags: jwt, auth0

I have front end app which call to back-end service and redirect user to Auth0 login, after success login Auth0 calling my back-end service and passing JWT token, I'm passing this token to my Front-end. Every time front-end calling to back-end services I'm calling Auth0 validation service.

Is it possible not to call each time Auth0? can I validate Auth0 token on my back-end or I need to sign my own token?

what is the best flow?

Answer (score 0):

ok, so Auth0 has a keys [https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/json-web-tokens/json-web-key-sets][1]
there is a [library https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa/tree/ee90de2a6dbf4668081f6d7fa4b0afae58fbadfb/examples/passport-demo][1] that can fetch this keys and validate token without making repeatable calls to Auth0.